How do I get the local coordinates of an emptxy
Effectively, I need to reference the coordinate space of an empty. Now in shader nodes, youd just use a texture coordinate node's "object" output. However, I cant seem to get the same result in geonodes that actually does rotation "correctly". I feel like this is basic geo nodes knowledge, yet Ive struggled trying to find any reference on how to do this correctly.



Could you tell us a little more about your setup and maybe share your blend file? It's not clear what exactly you do with the position you subtract here.
